# Java - Hibernate.cfg.xml - cannot resolve Driver in file

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Hibernate to connect my project to MySQL, and I get an error with the hibernate.cfg.xml file - cannot resolve package mysql (and package cj, jdbc, etc).

This is the code -

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/theprocess?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">Amit4089</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities.ClientsEntity"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities.InvoicesEntity"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities.OrdersEntity"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities.OrdersitemsEntity"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities.ProductsEntity"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The fifth row in the code is what I'm talking about.

The thing is that the dependencies are rightly declared and the same file works at my project partner.

(Spring Framework).

**#update 1 -**
Added dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Stack

```
19:28:27.282 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
19:28:27.298 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
19:28:27.298 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Unable to load or instantiate JPA aware resolver org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver. All properties will per default be traversable.
19:28:27.298 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
19:28:27.298 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
19:28:27.298 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
19:28:27.298 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
19:28:27.704 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
19:28:27.704 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
19:28:27.704 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraverseAllTraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
19:28:27.704 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
19:28:27.704 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
19:28:27.704 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
```

`
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace/error that you are getting?

Comment: @Yasin posted in the original post.

Comment: did you tried with  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property> ?

Comment: @KathirvelSubramanian where do I write it? in the pom.xml or in the hibernate file?

Comment: In hibernate file

Comment: Added the property, however there is no change. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is not clear from your post. But Make sure that the version of `MySQLDialect` is compatible with the version of MySQL you are using.

There are other `MySQLDialect` is for versions prior to 5.x. Then there is `MySQL55Dialect` and `MySQL57Dialect` as well, for version 5.5 and 5.7 respectively.